# How to restructure an object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to restructure my object like below. Basically, i want to remove a nesting from my object. How to achieve that using js.

**Actual:**

```
 var a =    [ 
    { clickedEvents:
         { 
           'event-element': 'a',
           'event-description': '',
           'timestamp': 1506673474238,
         } 
    },
     { clickedEvents:
         { 
           'event-element': 'b',
           'event-description': '',
           'timestamp': 1506673474123,
         } 
    }]
```

**Expected:**

```
var a =    [ 
     { 
           'event-element': 'a',
           'event-description': '',
           'timestamp': 1506673474238,

     },
     { 
           'event-element': 'b',
           'event-description': '',
           'timestamp': 1506673474123,

    }]
```

Comment: You have to recreate the object, try with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var a = [ 
        { clickedEvents:
             { 
               'event-element': 'a',
               'event-description': '',
               'timestamp': 1506673474238,
             } 
        },
         { clickedEvents:
             { 
               'event-element': 'b',
               'event-description': '',
               'timestamp': 1506673474123,
             } 
        }];

a = a.map(function(o){
    return o.clickedEvents;
});

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = a.map( el => el.clickedEvents );
```